# Accessing element of an array of struct inside a function in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, struct

So i have defined my own struct to be

```
typedef struct counter_Nval
{
    systs_t N;
    uint16_t cntr;
} countN_t;
```

I pass a pointer to pointer to this struct to a function, since i need to allocate an array of these struct

```
extern size_t __count_shnnr_N(size_t len, my_type_array *arr, countN_t **nNs)
{
    size_t ln = 1;
    size_t tmp = 1;

    *nNs = malloc(sizeof(**nNs) * ln--);

    nNs[ln]->N = arr[ln].N;
    nNs[ln]->cntr = 1;


    while (ln++ < len-1)
    {
        if (arr[ln].N == (*nNs+tmp-1)->N)
        {
            (*nNs+tmp-1)->cntr++;
        }
        else
        {
            *nNs = realloc(*nNs, sizeof(**nNs) * ++tmp);
            (*nNs+tmp-1)->N = arr[ln].N;
            (*nNs+tmp-1)->cntr = 1;
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Now the fact is that i faced some bad times trying to access elements of the array of struct inside the function as `nNs[tmp-1]->N` insted of `(*nNs+tmp-1)->N` i got `Segmentation fault` error, which is quite weird condiering that the first assignements `nNs[ln]->N = arr[ln].N;` and `nNs[ln]->cntr = 1;` work as intended.

What am i getting wrong? Aren't the two representations the same?

Comment: Instead of `(*nNs+tmp-1)->N)`, it would be clearer to write `(*nNs)[tmp-1].N`.  Even better would be to avoid the extra level of indirection until just before the `return`.  So you'd have a pointer `p`, then you could write `p[tmp-1].N`.  At the end, you'd do `*nNs = p;`.  This would not only be clearer, but faster as well.

Comment: And to answer your question, no, they aren't the same. `nNs[tmp-1]->N` is equivalent to `(*nNs[tmp-1]).N`, which is `(*(nNs[tmp-1])).N`, while `(*nNs+tmp-1)->N ` is equivalent to `(*(*nNs+tmp-1)).N`, which is `(*nNs)[tmp-1].N`.  As you can see, the two are very different.

Comment: Illuminating, thanks for both recommendations/explanations!